# How to remove the content type header from kafka messages produced by the spring cloud stream app starter sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

For twitter source it is creating a 30 bit header for each kafka messages if we use custom kafka consumer other than `@StreamListener` (Sink).
`@StreamListener` sends the messages correctly to the annotated method (no header). The problem is for each source the header size varies.
So how can I dynamically understand the header size of the messages since I'm using custom kafka consumer.?
Or How can I remove the header for each message.?

**UPDATE:-**

Please find below the message received in `kafka-console-consumer` while using a TCP Source.

```
�
  contentType"application/octet-stream"hello world
```

I just need to get the message only. In this case, hello world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.headerMode=raw` in source will remove the header while reading the message in consumer.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Kafka you are using? The reason why I am asking is that starting 0.11 Kafka supports native headers and you would not have this problem anymore.

Comment: Note that that requires overriding the Spring Cloud Stream binder in the pom to the kafka11 artifact (if you are using Ditmars). For other binders, set `spring.cloud.stream.binding.output.header-mode=raw`. See [the documentation about `headerMode`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_producer_properties).

Comment: Thanks for the support. My kafka version is 0.10. Do you mean that if I use 0.11 kafka, then the header send by the Source won't come in the kafka message. Currently I'm testing the same using a kafka-console-consumer. I have updated the message received through the console consumer.

Comment: As I said, set headermode=raw to remove the embedded header.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade to 0.11 kafka to work this, because I tried with my .10 but the header was still there. Also do I need to build the artifacts with kafka 11.?

Comment: It got worked. When we set the following property on the source app, the kafka consumer doesn't receives the header. `spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.headerMode=raw`. A slight change in the property suggested by @Gary Russell. Also the same is working for kafka 0.10.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I missed the `.producer.` part.

Answer (score 0):

Could also change this setting to remove the annoying header

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
```